# Microsoft Graph API findMeetingTimes is not returning available room correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using findMeetingTimes API and it is returning the same results all the time when I need the API to suggest me any available rooms. It is returning the closest room to me even though it is not available. I am entering other rooms but it is not returning them.
Also, I am in Ireland and trying to use Irish time. Only UTC is available as time option. Any ideas please?

```
{
    "attendees": [{
            "type": "required",
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "John Brady",
                "address": "test1@test.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "required",
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Micheal Travers",
                "address": "test2@test.com"
            }
        }

    ],
    "locationConstraint": {
        "isRequired": "true",
        "suggestLocation": "true",
        "locations": [{
                "resolveAvailability": "true",
                "displayName": "The Rockefeller Room/THE ROCK PHASE 1",
                "locationEmailAddress": "the.rockefeller.room@test.com"
            },
            {
                "resolveAvailability": "true",
                "displayName": "The Cork Room/THE ROCK PHASE 2",
                "locationEmailAddress": "the.cork.room@test.com"
            },
            {
                "resolveAvailability": "true",
                "displayName": "The Dublin Room/THE ROCK PHASE 2",
                "locationEmailAddress": "the.dublin.room@test.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "timeConstraint": {
        "activityDomain": "work",
        "timeslots": [{
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2017-10-23T09:00:00",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2017-10-23T17:00:00",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }]
    },
    "meetingDuration": "PT30M",
    "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
    "MaxCandidates": "10",
    "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the query parameters and what you send to the API. Thanks

Comment: I am executing from the Graph Explorer of graph.microsoft.com as above

Comment: That's the problem that even I am facing .

Answer (score 0):

Same here created 2 users and 2 rooms booked one user into one room for the morning using outlook365 web pages and queried the api for both rooms and both users. 4 queries. the user I booked was unavailable for booking on the morning which is correct but the other user had both rooms to choose from for that very same morning. Obviously not working.